# npm install giving error 404- HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Res.FormBuilder - Not found

Tags: npm, installation, hyperlink

When I tried npm install I got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie2kx.jpg)